# Discord.py Stop ignoring own bot messages

Tags: python, discord.py

So i have been trying to do a little project where i need to fo following command:

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("!test")
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Whats Up!")
```

Basicly **I** want to write "!start" then the **bot** will write "!test" and becasue of this "!test" also "Whats Up!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bot` has a `_skip_check` function that the constructor will set to either ignore the bots commands or ignore everything but the bots commands.  We can change it to never skip anything:

```
bot = commands.Bot('!')

bot._skip_check = lambda x, y: False

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("!test")


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Whats Up!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
    await bot.invoke(ctx)
```

This is a pretty fragile workaround, don't be surprised if the implementation changes and this suddenly stopped working.  A more stable change would be to subclass `Bot` and write your own `get_context` method that doesn't perform this check.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for misunderstanding your question. I tested it myself and turns out that the bot extension in discord.py **automatically** makes the bot not reply to itself.
To disable this, you have to either change your version of discord.py (not reccomended) or use the standard library without the bot extension (somewhat reccomended).

But why do you even want the bot to respond to itself? 99.9% of the time this isn't needed, you can just make the bot send two messages with a delay inbetween. If you are 100% convinced you need to have the bot reply to itself, then I reccomend getting by without the bot extension.